# Only include and AND in the where clause if the field has a postive length

Tags: t-sql

trying to add a conditional AND.

I don't want to check for the Data field match if the @Data has nothing

```
select distinct mo.ModelId,
                mo.ModelName        
from Model mo
     join MaModelar mmy on mmy.ModelID = mo. ModelID
     join [Application] a on a.MaModelar ID = mmy.MaModelar ID
     join Appltitle t on t.ApplTID = a.ApplicationID
where mmy.MakeId = 331
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(t.Name) > 0
        THEN
            and (t.Name = 'A.T.V.') 
        END
order by mo.ModelName asc
```

**Let me summarize in different words:**

I don't want to query on (Modelid AND @Note) if @Note is invalid.  Invalid means @Note is empty or null.  So I am trying to add some kind of conditional statement that first checks @Note and if it's valid include it in the where clause as an AND.  So if @Note is valid (len > 1) then this query should include  mmy.MakeId = 331 AND t.Data = 'A.T.V.'.

If @Note is not valid, then the query would just have  WHERE mmy.MakeId = 331 and leave out the AND and it would not try to check for @Note along with mmy.MakeId.

I tried this also:

```
select distinct mo.ModelId,
        mo.ModelName        
from Model mo
     join MaModelar mmy on mmy.ModelID = mo. ModelID
     join [Application] a on a.MaModelar ID = mmy.MaModelar ID
     join Appltitle t on t.ApplTID = a.ApplicationID
WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Name))) < 1
    THEN where mmy.ModelId = @ModelId
ELSE
    where mmy.ModelId = @ModelId
    AND substring(n.Name, CHARINDEX(']', n.Name) + 2, LEN(n.Name)) = @Name
```

Comment: changed the param name to Name instead of data to make it more obvious that it's a field.  Problem is the name field is sometimes null or a bunch of spaces so I don't want to add the "and" portion as part of the query with ModelId if the @Note is null or empty.  So basically if it is null or empty the query would stop at the where and just query on modelid

Answer (score 2):

use

```
select distinct mo.ModelId,
                mo.ModelName        
from Model mo
     join MaModelar mmy on mmy.ModelID = mo. ModelID
     join [Application] a on a.MaModelar ID = mmy.MaModelar ID
     join Appltitle t on t.ApplTID = a.ApplicationID
where mmy.MakeId = 331 AND ( LEN(t.Data) < 1 OR t.Data = 'A.T.V.')
order by mo.ModelName asc
```

EDIT - as per comments:

try

```
select distinct mo.ModelId,
                mo.ModelName        
from Model mo
     join MaModelar mmy on mmy.ModelID = mo. ModelID
     join [Application] a on a.MaModelar ID = mmy.MaModelar ID
     join Appltitle t on t.ApplTID = a.ApplicationID
where mmy.MakeId = 331 AND t.Data = 'A.T.V.'
order by mo.ModelName asc
```

Comment: this doesn't work......because I'm getting a ton of results, not just results for A.T.V.

Comment: it is exactly (in a mathematical sense) the same as what you posted in your question... since I am not sure what result your really want I added another query... please check that... otherwise describe your goal with sample data...

Answer (score 1):

Just have a nested filter:

```
WHERE mmy.MakeID = 331
AND (T.Data = '' OR t.Data = 'A.T.V.')
```

Using the `LEN` function will make the query non-SARGable so I would avoid that if possible.

Comment: +1, and that, in turn, can be changed further into `…AND t.Data IN ('', 'A.T.V.')`.

Comment: @AndriyM - good point, I thought of that when writing the answer but left it as an `OR` expecting OP to comment at some point about `NULL`s.

Comment: doesn't work 100%. I need to account for empty strings so I guess I should trim and then check LEN

Comment: `''` and `'   '` are equivalent for varchar comparisons, so that is something to consider.  `LEN` will drastically slow down the query though, so bear that in mind.  It forces a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your and clause to

```
AND 
  (substring(n.Name, CHARINDEX(']', n.Name) + 2, LEN(n.Name)) = @Name

     or @Name is null)
```

Note: there's no way to force the DB Engine to short-circuit the OR clause.

I also do this in some cases

```
DECLARE @IsNameEmpty bit 

IF @Name is null or @Name = '' or @Name = 'Some Special value'
   @IsNameEmpty = 1
else
   @IsNameEmpty = 0
```

and then I do this instead

```
AND 
     (substring(n.Name, CHARINDEX(']', n.Name) + 2, LEN(n.Name)) = @Name

     or @IsNameEmpty = 1)
```

Which makes it easier if I have a query that uses `@Name` several times and I don't feel like writing each condition.

Comment: You are checking for null after?  shouldn't it be first before the substring check?

Comment: oh I see if the first bombs, then if the second bombs also, then it short circuits basically...and kinda wipes that last check out

Comment: Sadly it doesn't matter so do whichever you perfer

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to worry about null fields. Your check t.Data = 'A.T.V.' will fail if the column is empty.

Comment: He doesn't want it to fail, he wants BOTH blank fields AND fields where the value is `A.T.V.`